# Finding an ellipse of minimum area that encloses a set of points

Tags: functions, mathematical-optimization, fitting, geometry

Is there a built-in function or set of functions in Mathematica that can take a set of points in the x-y plane and determine the ellipse of minimum area that contains all of the points? I am sure there are algorithms out there, but oftentimes I have found that after I implement an algorithm with a good number of steps I then come across a more efficient way to do it in Mathematica with built-in functions.

Comment: You are looking for [`BoundingRegion`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BoundingRegion.html)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You are looking for [`BoundingRegion`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BoundingRegion.html) with the `"MinEllipse"` region specification:

```
SeedRandom[1234]
points = RandomReal[{-10, 10}, {20, 2}];
reg = BoundingRegion[points, "MinEllipse"];

Graphics[
  {
    EdgeForm[Black], LightGray, reg,
    Red, PointSize[0.02], Point[points]
  },
  Axes -> True
]
```

[image]

If speed is of the essence, a faster method is available through the `"FastEllipse"` option. You can compare the two results and their areas:

```
min = BoundingRegion[points, "MinEllipse"];
fast = BoundingRegion[points, "FastEllipse"];

Graphics[{
   EdgeForm[Black],
   Opacity[0.3, Green], min,
   Opacity[0.1, Red], fast,
   Opacity[1, Blue], PointSize[0.02], Point[points],
   Inset[Style[Round@Area@min, 18, Darker@Green], {4, 2}],
   Inset[Style[Round@Area@fast, 18, Red], {-7, 11}]
  },
  Axes -> True
]
```

[image: results from min vs fast ellipse]